# Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glibc, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I was trying to run a script on a remote server I am logged in, but it reported the error:
 `` bin/track.linux: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by bin/track.linux) ``

So, I checked the current version, which in fact was 2.28. I went back to my local environment (Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL) and there was the same version, too.

Then, as suggested by multiple forums, I upgraded my environment to Ubuntu 20.04 and I checked the version, which is indeed
`ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.14) 2.31`
`Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

However, when I tried to run again the script on the server, it reported once again:
 `` bin/track.linux: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by bin/track.linux) `` and I checked the version of GLIBC, which was indeed `ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10+deb10u2) 2.28`.

So, I have some questions:

a) why when I ask the version of GLIBC by doing `ldd --version`, locally it refers to Ubuntu GLIBC and on the server it refers to Debian GLIBC?

b) why are the two versions different? I mean why the GLIBC version on the server differs from the local GLIBC version? Should I disconnect from the server and try to reconnect again?

(P.s. Sorry in advance for my non-computer science language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why are the two versions different?

You have two separate systems. One of them (local) got upgraded. That has *no effect* on the other (the one on the server), which stayed the same (old).

When you try to run the program (which requires GLIBC-2.29 or above) on the server (which has GLIBC-2.28), it doesn't work.

Why are you surprised by this outcome?